# SQL Server query to report Logins per hour over a given timeframe by day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to generate some SQL for a report I am working on (SQL Server 2005). Basically I'm trying to report the number of logins per hour within a timeframe period. When there is no record, I will need to return zero for the hour component, and same with a day, if there is no records for the given day, to return zero's for the 24 hr intervals for that day.

So far I am have the SQL query to return the 24 hr interval results for an individual given day. I'm just trying to expand on it now to do it over multiple days (say 1 week for example). Hopefully I have provided enough info :P

My current code is :

```
--Create the temp table to store the 24hr
Declare @Hours Table (Hour int);
Declare @i as int;
Set @i = 0
While @i < 24
Begin
   Insert into @Hours
   Values(@i);

   Set @i = @i + 1;
End;

Select  
   [Hour of Day],
   count([Login]) as [total]

From
(
   SELECT       
      DATEPART(hh, [date] )  AS [Hour of Day]
      ,activity_log.date as [Login]
   FROM activity_log
   where 
   category = 'Login' 
   and description like '%logged in%'
   and[date] between '2012/06/01' and '2012/06/02'
   Union ALL

   SELECT Hour, NULL

   From @Hours

 ) as Data

 GROUP BY [Hour of Day]

 ORDER BY [Hour of Day]
```

I have included an attachment of the sample results I'm trying to achieve.

[Sample results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NNOz.png)

Comment: basically you'd just want the equivalent of `group by year(date), month(date), day(date) where date between xxx and yyy`

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I'm finding it a bit tricky integrating the day part with the union so that the hour components are grouped by the relevant day as well. any psuedo code tips you can provide?

Comment: instead of a union, use a join. `select .. from @hours left join activity_log on @hours.hour = datepart(hour, activity_log)` or something thereabouts.

Comment: As a side note, please don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp values, [especially on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  But yeah, joining as if it were a time-based calendar table should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Clockwork-Muse..I'm guessing however, I would need to create some sort of "calendar" table in order to get the consecutive day part of it and join against that?